# Arduino ECG sputtering out totally random values

Tags: c, bluetooth, arduino

Hello StackExchange community,

I have encountered a problem in my ECG/EKG design.  I am trying to create the ECG using Arduino as a microcontroller to send/retrieve heart rate measurements via Bluetooth (JY-MCU).  I know my circuit is working because when I place an LED in op-amp output and its ground, I get a slight dimming of the light if I gently put my hand on the leads.  I know the issue is with my code.  I have been working on this project for a while and still can't be able to find a solution.  Here is my schematic.

[image: 1]

Sorry, you might want to flip your screen over to see the pic!  Here is my code that I think is incorrect.  The code is just at a bare minimum.

```
// External variables
const int  signal = 8;    // Pin connected to the filtered signal from the circuit
unsigned long time;   
unsigned long frequency;
char freq[3];

// Internal variables
double period = 2000;
double starttime = 2000;
double input = 0;
double lastinput = 0;
unsigned long death = 0;

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins

void setup() {
pinMode(signal, INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
delay(500);

time = millis();
input = digitalRead(signal);

 period = time - starttime; // Compute the time between the previous beat and the one that has just been detected
 starttime = time; // Define the new time reference for the next period computing
 death = time;
 frequency = 60000/period;
 freq[0] = frequency/100+48; // Sort the hundreds character and convert it in ASCII
 freq[1] = (frequency/10)%10+48; // Sort the thents character and convert it in ASCII
 freq[2] = frequency%10+48; // Sort the units character and convert it in ASCII
 Serial.println(freq);
}
```

All I'm getting is either 120 or 119 as my value.  It fluctuates between those two.  I tried changing my resistors out but that didn't do anything.  I also completely took the wire between pin 8 and the breadboard out, and it still fluctuated between 119 to 120.  I don't have any idea what is going on here!  I would appreciate it if someone could help me out here.  Thanks!

Comment: It seems unlikely you are going to get a useful measurement from something so simple feeding a digital input - you may be seeing power line noise picked up by what is effectively an antenna.  I suspect this is often done with a good analog front end and ADC, followed by a software fourier transform to find interesting frequency components (which are not necessarily the strongest) in the data.  Do be careful of electrical safety when using skin electrodes!

Comment: Oh OK.  Even if I cover the lead, I still get the same issue.  Do you know what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't doing anything remotely useful. It's certainly not measuring input frequency - in fact it does not even care what the value of the input signal is and will behave the same regardless of whatever is going on externally. All it is doing is measuring the time between calls to `loop()` and converting this time to a frequency in cycles per minute. Since you have a 500 ms delay in `loop()` you get a frequency of 2 Hz = 120 cycles / minute, which is consistent with the numbers you are seeing.

To be brutally honest I doubt your circuit will ever be able to measure ECG signals even if you do get the code right - it's just too crude - but so that you can at least measure *something* frequency-related you might want to try and implement the following code in `loop()`:

```
input = digitalRead(signal);
while (input == digitalRead(signal))
    ; // wait for input signal to change state (sync)
start = millis();
while (input != digitalRead(signal))
    ; // wait for input signal to change state (first part of period)
while (input == digitalRead(signal))
    ; // wait for input signal to change state (one complete period)
end = millis();
period = end - start;
freq = 60000 / period;
```

Note that this will hang if your input signal is not changing state regularly.

Note also that this will only give a useful frequency measurement if you have a completely clean input signal, i.e. a signal that only changes state at the frequency of interest, with no noise transitions. In practice you may well just end up measuring the frequency of mains hum or other background noise.